# Not able to view on Command line interface when a callback function is invoked using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, hyperterminal, hyperterm

When killing a process with the process id in the command line interface (`hyperTerminal` for windows), the callback function having  "`Why are you trying to terminate me?!?  :-)`"  is not getting reflected in the console.

In the first shell I am running using the command `node myfilename.js`
after running I am getting output as :  `Node is running as process #processid`

and to kill this process,
I am running the command: `taskkill /F /PID processid`
in a different shell

The Code is given below:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');


process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
    process.stderr.write("Why are you trying to terminate me?!?  :-)\n");
});

console.log("Node is running as process #" + process.pid);
```

After running my command, the process is getting terminated with message:
`SUCCESS: The process with PID processid has been terminated.`

but in the console I am not getting the output (`Why are you trying to terminate me?!?  :-)`) which is required.

Comment: You should probably tag this with the appropriate MS Windows terminal you are using.

Comment: Hi thanks for the feedback. Btw i am using hyper terminal for windows x64

Comment: Have you tried `taskkill` without the `/F` flag? I believe that flag skips over the bit about sending signals...

Comment: I have tried without the /F flag and I'm getting message  Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).